# How to design table for greater than and less than information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble designing the appropriate table to represent a setting for an application.

How can we store greater than and less than information into an mssql table?

I need to save the following "settings" in an application. Basically It represents how many seconds it took for the Armor to be penetrated in seconds.

For example on the Light armor, how would I save that as a table in a db.  How would I store the value:  If seconds are less than 389?

In one table or multiple?

I want to save the greater than or less than range not the actual data.

```
Type            Needs      Meets     Exceeds
LightJediArmor  < 389      390-480   > 480
HeavyJediArmor  < 1000     1000-2000 > 2000
```

Comment: You can probably use one table with a "Type" column, a "MinimumValue" column, and a "MaximumValue" column.  The "meets" in your example would be any value between the minimum and maximum values.  Can you post example queries for how you'd like to use this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Type   MeetThreshold   ExceedsThreshold
Light  390             480
Heavy  1000            2000
```

Comment: Ok So then for everything else they can be derived from these?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Can you provide an example to illustrate?

Comment: What I mean is then for Needs which is not on your table can be calculated through queries or code.

Comment: Exactly. Needs can be calculated from these.